# Is there a way in SQL to return only the items that WOULD have grouped together using a group by multiple columns clause

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a single SQL table in Redshift:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
| row |                 ID                   | countrycode |    date    |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
| 10  | e498bb7e-3084-3e4e-a5e7-9a10cd7a19b8 |     BRA     | 2019-06-05 |
| 11  | ce79f8d8-a473-3414-a867-f453ee7fe91e |     CHL     | 2019-06-12 |
| 12  | aaa425bb-46d6-39f0-be14-b5f962cb1e61 |     CZE     | 2019-06-07 |
| 13  | da16bf46-8f0b-3184-bd65-c5f5b5455392 |     CZE     | 2019-06-07 |
+-----+--------------------------------------+-------------+------------+
```

And Id like to return only the ID, countrycode and date (though Id settle for returning just the ID) of the items that have the same countrycode AND date as each other i.e if I did a group by without the ID column they would have combined.  Referring to the example table above, I'd like to just return the ID's from rows 12 and 13 since they have the same country code AND date as each other.

The goal of the query is to find unique ID's that were in particular country on the same date as each other ie. two unique ID's that were in the same country on the same date, but not a singular ID that spent two days in one country.

Comment: Ahh. yes. I copied the wrong cells in making the table. I fixed the example. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where countrycode = t.countrycode and date = t.date and id <> t.id
)
```

Comment: I had to fix the example table. I accidentally pasted identical ID's which would make this solution more viable. I'm going to edit the question further as well to add more detail. Thanks!

Comment: I changed my answer after you edited. Did you try it?

Comment: Would you mind just telling me what "SELECT 1" does? whats the 1?

Comment: 1 could also be 0 or null, it does not matter. What is important is that select returns *something*.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by countrycode, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

If your ids can be duplicated -- which is a very strange thing for a column called `id` -- then you can still use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
              min(id) over (partition by countrycode, date) as min_id,
              max(id) over (partition by countrycode, date) as max_id
      from t
     ) t
where min_id <> max_id;
```

If you wanted the ids as a long string, you could also use aggregation:

```
select countrycode, date, listagg(id, ',') within group (order by id) as ids
from t
group by countrycode, date
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Really close to what I was looking for except it returns unique ids that have been in a country for more than two days but its the same ID.  My goal (which I should have stated) is to find unique ID's that were in the same country at the same time. Gives me something to go on too. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why Gordon's first query doesn't meet your requirement. It shows all unique IDs where they've been in the same country more than once per day

Comment: It also would return a single ID that had 2+ entries on one day in one country. I was looking for unique ID's that were essentially in the same country on the same date. Gordons answer returned an ID that had two entries for date and country in a single day, but it was the same ID, if that makes sense...I have to play around more with the answers and on the full set but thats how it appeared to me.

Comment: @Zack . . . I would still advise you to use window functions in Redshift.  You can phrase the query (which I've done) to handle duplicate ids.

Comment: OK. I'll give it a shot.  Yeah, the ID's are not unique in this data set. Each ID is an individual but that individual can have multiple entries for different timestamps and locations.  Thanks!